# Ubuntu 22.04 which sensor temperature is the CPU?

Tags: cpu, overheating, temperature

The sensors command lists the temperature of various components in the system, but which one is the CPU? How to link these labels with system components?

```
sensors
                                                                                                   m33: Sat Sep 23 09:26:09 2023

iwlwifi_1-virtual-0
Adapter: Virtual device
temp1:            N/A

enp212s0-pci-d400
Adapter: PCI adapter
PHY Temperature:  +64.0°C
MAC Temperature:  +64.0°C

nvme-pci-d200
Adapter: PCI adapter
Composite:    +32.9°C  (low  = -273.1°C, high = +81.8°C)
                       (crit = +84.8°C)
Sensor 1:     +32.9°C  (low  = -273.1°C, high = +65261.8°C)
Sensor 2:     +34.9°C  (low  = -273.1°C, high = +65261.8°C)

nvme-pci-4100
Adapter: PCI adapter
Composite:    +33.9°C  (low  =  -0.1°C, high = +69.8°C)
                       (crit = +79.8°C)

k10temp-pci-00c3
Adapter: PCI adapter
Tctl:         +46.2°C

enp211s0-pci-d300
Adapter: PCI adapter
PHY Temperature:  +46.0°C
MAC Temperature:  +46.0°C

nvme-pci-cd00
Adapter: PCI adapter
Composite:    +34.9°C  (low  = -273.1°C, high = +81.8°C)
                       (crit = +84.8°C)
Sensor 1:     +34.9°C  (low  = -273.1°C, high = +65261.8°C)
Sensor 2:     +37.9°C  (low  = -273.1°C, high = +65261.8°C)
```